# Loading the active directory user and their associated Computers

Tags: c#, active-directory

Hello Everyone i am trying to develop a  program that will list will all the user of Active Directory and when i select one user the program should be able to show the computers associated with that user. i.e   the Computers that are accessible to that AD user.
I have written code to list all  user but no idea how to list the computers associated with that user.
Here is my code to load AD User into datatable:

```
DataTable dtUser= new DataTable();
    try
    {            
        DirectoryEntry dom = Domain.GetComputerDomain().GetDirectoryEntry();

        DirectorySearcher dsAllUsers = new DirectorySearcher(dom);
        dsAllUsers.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        dsAllUsers.Filter = "(objectCategory=Person)";

        SearchResultCollection result = dsAllUsers.FindAll();
        dtUser.Columns.Add("CustodianName");
        dtUser.Columns.Add("Email");
        dtUser.Columns.Add("Title");
        dtUser.Columns.Add("Dept.");           

        foreach (SearchResult rs in result)
        {
            DataRow newRow = dtUser.NewRow();

            if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value != null)
                newRow["CustodianName"] = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value.ToString();

            if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value != null)
                newRow["Email"] = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();

            if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["title"].Value != null)
                    newRow["Title"] = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["title"].Value.ToString();

            if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["department"].Value != null)
                newRow["Dept."] = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["department"].Value.ToString();

            dtUser.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
        return dtUser;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
```

Comment: I don't believe standard LDAP/Active Directory has anything like this. Computers are just another class of AD objects - but there's no "link" between a user and one (or multiple) computer(s). If you have implemented this, it would have to be a custom attribute on the LDAP `computer` class - and if it's custom, then *you* must know what it is!

Comment: Thanks @marc_s.but i think there must be a way,In my point of view if i should find the user's Group/Member and find the computers associated with that Group/Member.Is it possible to do so?

Comment: As I said - **no**, I don't think there's any attribute in standard LDAP/AD that links/connects users/groups to computers.

Comment: So you are saying that:- there is no way to know the computers that are associated with the particular user of AD

Comment: No, there is not. Computers are not "assigned" to users, there's no `belongsTo` attribute or anything like that. Computers are stand-alone objects in AD. Anything that "links" users and computers is probably something your organization does - but it's **NOT** represented in AD.

Comment: @marc_s so then what will you do if u were given the task as mine ?

Comment: As I'm trying to explain: unless your organization has **extended** the AD schema to include specific, custom attributes to link computers to users, this information **CANNOT** be retrieved from Active Directory ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe standard LDAP/Active Directory has anything like this.

Computers are just another class of AD objects - but there's no "link" between a user and one (or multiple) computer(s) - there's no `belongsTo` attribute on the `computer` class, nor is there a `computers` collection on `User`.

If your organization has implemented an extension to the default AD schema (which is entirely possible!), it's a custom solution, and then *you* must know what it is! :-)